# x-editable: customize an x-editable for having more field, but only one editable

Tags: arrays, twitter-bootstrap, submit, x-editable

in these days I'm going crazy about x-editables...I can't understand how customize an x-editable to obtain a complex array of fields.

I need to create an x-editable customized, that has this behavior: **a checklist (so an array of value) but with an input text field for every check item**.

I need something like this (*simulated with paint shop*)

[image: need this!!]

This x-editable when submit must produce an output like (just a retouched example)

[image: submit]

How can I create an x-editable with this behaviour/functionality?

Pratically a collection of objects, where the object have two fields: id, number of fruit.

Thanks in advance to all.

Comment: I think that you don't need x-editable for your purpose.. Just try to use x-editable as it should be and add some code to handle your "special" objects

Comment: Thank you very much for your attention, Yuri!  I'm sorry if it annoys you, but nevertheless I searched the Internet how to do it, I can not find anything that would help me: Can you suggest something to obtain this "customization"? Because I do not know how to move ..

Comment: I mean, you can handle them as single x-editable objects, and before sending, your merge your desired values into the needed object, and manually send it via `$.ajax()`

Comment: Exactly what I need! And think that is the best way insted customize a complex element...but how merge? This is what I don't understand how do so...the problems is still the same: how merge all this data to other submit? Thank in advance for your time..you really help me in these days...

Comment: What do you need checkboxes for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following comments, check this solution (referred to fiddle):

```
$('#save').on('click', function(){
    var fruits = [];
    $('.editable').each(function(i, v){
        /* store it as you like */
        var name = $(v).data('name');
        var value = $(v).editable('getValue'); //x-editable stores value under 'name' index, like {"banana": 10}
        var fruit = {"fruit_id": name, "num": value[name]}
        fruits.push(fruit);
    }).promise().done(function(){
        // promise() will wait .each() loop to finish before going ahead
        $.ajax({
            url: "/post",
            data: {fruits: fruits},
            success: frunction(data){
                /*....*/
            }
        });
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/YuriJF/yLhwdjje/1/)

Comment: you're great!! I don't know the "promise" method..thank you very much!!!!